# Vue-cli-3: не устанавливается

Tags: vue.js

Не удается установить. Выдает ошибку:

```
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for flatmap-stream
```

NPM не находит пакет `flatmap-stream`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap-stream

Я так понимаю, это только ждать, когда разработчики Vue, внесут изменения в пакет?

Comment: Скорее всего проблемы с пакетом flatmap-stream связаны с этой [историей](https://habr.com/company/globalsign/blog/431204/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vue-cli-3` удалось установить. Помогло обновление `npm`. Хоть у меня и был установлен `npm` последней версии